# IBM COS SDK - Access bucket using service ID

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm able to using the example in https://github.com/ibm/ibm-cos-sdk-python/ to access the bucket using the Service Credentials information.  Is there a way to access the bucket using service ID and its API?  Or I have to create service credentials for each service ID?  I'm trying to limit read and write access of the service ID to a specific bucket.
Thanks for any advice you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of Service Credentials using the same Service ID.  That way you can manage permissions for a single ID, and any changes in that Service ID's roles will be applied to any Service Credentials generated using that ID.  Some more info is in the [IAM docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/serviceidaccess.html#serviceidpolicy).

Comment: Thanks Nick for the suggestion.  If I don't want service ID to see a certain bucket, then I should have separate service ID instead of different service credentials, is that correct?

Comment: Also, do you know there is a way to create the service credentials programmatically (not using UI)?

Comment: Yes - you would create another service ID. Note that when you create a service credential in the UI, it gives you the option of generating a fresh service ID for the new credential.

Comment: And sort of. There is a REST API but it is not yet publicly available.  You can use the Bluemix CLI, but oddly enough the command is to create a “service key”, which contains the credential. Yes, this terminology is difficult to keep straight. :)